# AssetRegistry.get function is not returning the complete object in Hyperledger Composer

Tags: inheritance, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

It is an inheritance, Record has a reference of SampleAsset and SampletAsset has a reference of SampleParticipant.
In transaction I am sending record object and when i am printing it on console It is showing complete information of Sample asset and complete information of SampleParticipant,
while I am trying to fetch it using get method it is not returning the complete information of the objects. Please check the screenshot: [Record Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGnfa.png) [getObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dq8X.png)
SampleParticipant(owner) reference is not there.

Please check the below chain code:

```
namespace org.test.network

asset SampleAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  --> SampleParticipant owner
}

asset Record identified by recordId {
  o String recordId
  --> SampleAsset asset
}

participant SampleParticipant identified by participantId {
  o String participantId
  o Double balance
}

transaction getRecord {
  --> Record record
}
```

Transaction Function:

```
async function get(getTx) {
  const record = getTx.record;

  let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.test.network.Record');

  let recordFromReg = await assetRegistry.get(record.$identifier);
  console.log(record);
  console.log(recordFromReg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When a transaction function is called the 'relationships' are all 'resolved' automatically as [explained here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts).

When you retrieve an Asset you have to 'resolve' the relationship yourself.  Ideally there would be a '.resolve' method that would do it for you, but as [this issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3454) points out it is not present in the runtime API.

When/if you write any code using the JavaScript API you will find that there is a [resolve method](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/client-assetregistry#resolve).

Comment: thanks it clear my doubt. But it should resolve the it do in transaction function, as when for abstract things you just can't write multiple transaction or else there will be a huge tree of if statement in transaction function to resolve all the relationship. I tried resolve method but it is throwing error as .resolve is not a function.

Comment: I think there should be a .resolve in the Transaction function (runtime api) but I doubt it will be fixed now.  I assume you have seen this news: https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125