# Why can't I obtain the attributes of a participant that is attached to an asset?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to update an asset. For that, I want to check that only the user who created it (here: the issueingPhysician) can update it.
**The problem: I can get "itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician", but "itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician.userId" is undefined.**

To illustrate, I put an error message into my code (see below) and tested the code in Composer Playground. It returned:

```
"Error: Only the physician who issued the prescription can change it. The current participant is: 1772 But the issueing Physican has userId: undefined The Issueing Physician is:Relationship {id=org.[...].participant.Physician#1772} His name is: undefined"
```

The Fabric Version is hlfv12.
For testing purposes, I gave all participants admin rights.

The js-Code for the transaction:

```
/**
* Update a prescription.
* @param {org.[..].UpdatePrescription} transaction
* @transaction
*/
```

```js
async function processUpdatingOfPrescription(transaction) {
     var prescriptionItemAssetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.[..].Prescription');
     var itemToUpdate = await prescriptionItemAssetRegistry.get(transaction.recordId);
     if (getCurrentParticipant().userId == itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician.userId && itemToUpdate.status !== 'DELETED') {
     // [...]
     }
     else { // only to demonstrate that it is the same user:
         throw new Error('Only the physician who issued the prescription can change it. The current participant is: ' + getCurrentParticipant().userId + 
                    ' But the issueing Physican has userId: ' + itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician.userId + 'The itemToUpdate is:' + itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician)
}
```

}

The asset in the cto-File:

```
asset Prescription identified by recordId {
  o String recordId
  o String prescribedDrug
  --> Physician issueingPhysician
 }
```

The user (=physician) In the cto-File:

```
participant Physician identified by userId {
  o String userId
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}
```

The transaction in the cto-File:

```
transaction UpdatePrescription {
  o String recordId
}
```

I would like to get a value for "itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician.userId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you retrieve an Asset you have to 'resolve' the relationship (`itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician.userId`) yourself. See the answer [AssetRegistry.get function is not returning the complete object in Hyperledger Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816276/assetregistry-get-function-is-not-returning-the-complete-object-in-hyperledger-c) for more info and the related issue tracker and [status on Composer](https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125) there.

For your identifier comparison - best to use `getIdentifier()` to get the singular identifier of each resource instance, for correct comparison of the identifiers themselves:

try:

'NS' below is 'org.acme' in my scenario FYI.

```
async function processUpdatingOfPrescription(transaction) {
     var prescriptionItemAssetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry(NS + '.Prescription');
     var itemToUpdate = await prescriptionItemAssetRegistry.get(transaction.recordId);
     console.log('participant is ' + getCurrentParticipant().getIdentifier() );
     if (getCurrentParticipant().getIdentifier() == itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician.getIdentifier() && itemToUpdate.status !== 'DELETED') {
        console.log("yes they match !! ");
     }
     else { // only to demonstrate that it is the same user:
         throw new Error('Only the physician who issued the prescription can change it. The current participant is: ' + getCurrentParticipant().getIdentifier() + 
                    ' But the issueing Physican has userId: ' + itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician.getIdentifier() + 'The itemToUpdate is:' + itemToUpdate.issueingPhysician);
     }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much!